Template for keycloak:23 invitation email
Using keycloak in version 23 there's no preexisting email template for invitation to organization.
It is possible to write a invitation-email.ftl template and it will work just fine. The only thing is that organization.name doesn't work (I think that the support for that has been added in the later versions). Is there a way of providing the organization's name variable to the custom template?
